# Problem translation of terms menu - Drupal 8.5.1 - Distribution VarBase

Tags: views, console

how are they? 
I have a problem with the menu item translation. when i make click in button translate i have a issue i attach image.

I am using `Drupal 8.5.1` and the `distribution VarBase 8.x-4.16`.

[image]

Error: After the click, we see the following error.
[image]

El sitio web encontró un error inesperado. Vuelva a intentarlo más tarde.InvalidArgumentException: Field content_translation_source is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 580 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php). Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->get('content_translation_source') (Line: 44)
Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationMetadataWrapper->getSource() (Line: 120)
Drupal\content_translation\Controller\ContentTranslationController->Drupal\content_translation\Controller{closure}('es')
array_filter(Array, Object) (Line: 122)
Drupal\content_translation\Controller\ContentTranslationController->overview(Object, 'menu_link_content')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

I hope favorable answers!!
As always thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, going to **admin/config/regional/content-language** and check the box in Custom menu link and solve the problem.